# Remove Eclipse indentation for non-curly-brackets if statement

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I would like to remove the indentation for non-curly-brackets if statements in Eclipse (Java EE).

I know this is bad practice, but there is so much going on in my Java file, and every time I format it using Ecliplse's formatter, it makes the code look uglier than ugly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it makes your code look uglier than ugly, then *perhaps* your methods are too large. Your phrase "so much going on" would indicate that there is no 
"perhaps" about that. So rather than trying to squeeze an `if` statement down to one line, you should learn to write better code.

Comment: @Andreas give me a way to DM you and try to write better code xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want that your non-curly-brackets if statements like follows?

```
if(true) return 0;
```

Then go Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit (Active profile) -> rename it -> Control Statements -> select "Keep 'then' statement on same line", "Keep 'else' statement..." and "Keep 'else if' on one line"; and press Ok.

I hope that helps.